# internationalization of date formats in play framework

Tags: java, internationalization, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have internationalized my play app using messages.en, messages.de etc. However, the US and UK have different date format preferences.

The play documentation is a bit unclear and I thought you had to use 2-letter ISO codes but it seems that the 3-letter ISO language codes work in play as well.

I found eng and enu here and plugged it into play and success. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488%28v=cs.20%29.aspx

I can't find them documented in official ISO though and would prefer that play be a bit more clear that 3-letter codes work so I know it's a feature and not a bug.

In general, any recommendations on how to best do the date formats here? Is tying them to the language selection a good idea or better to give users a choice independent of language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set date format for Play, you define it in your config file, rather than specifically in a messages file here - http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/configuration#date.format

Play says the following about choosing between the 2 character code (language code) and the language and country code, here - http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/i18n#languages

> You can use language/country pair if you want to distinguish between
>   variant, such as en_US and en_GB, or zh_CN and zh_TW. However, be
>   aware that some users may only expose a language and not a country in
>   their Accept-language. For that reason, you should always provide the
>   “naked” language (e.g. en).
>
> For example, if most of your users are from US but you also want to
>   support British English, it is recommended to use simply “en” of US
>   English and “en_GB” for British English.

It does not specifically mention the 3 character codes. However, Play uses the Java Locale object for internationalisation, so if you look at the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) for that object, you can see reference to the 2 character code only, and not the 3 character code. So, it is probably safer to rely on the 2 character code (or country and language code, such as `en_gb`), as although Locale seems to support 3 country codes, you cannot guarantee all!

Comment: I read that doc file a few times and didn't see this paragraph. I'll refactor to the language code as recommended. So my messages.enu and messages.eng files will now be messages.en (defaulting to US for English if user doesn't support country) and messages.en_GB for uk. Thanks!